# AngularJS Service duplicate response in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm calling the following service:
Get accounts details

First piece of code in my controller:

```
//resp is coming from an $http sync request, above the below request.
    for (var i = 0; i < resp.rows; ++i) { 
         userService.getAccountsBalance($rootScope.userid, resp[i]['Acct_Number']).then(function(data){

                console.log(data.bal) // shows two duplicate balances
            });
    }
```

In my service:

```
app.service('userService', function($rootScope, $q){
    var deferred = $q.defer();  


    this.getAccountsBalance = function(userid, accountNum){
        console.log(userid + "    " + accountNum)
        var req = <my $http request>
        req.send().then(function(resp){
            deferred.resolve(resp.responseJSON);        
        }); 

        console.log(deferred.promise) //// prints two balances JSON objects with no duplicate
        return deferred.promise; 
    }
});
```

My question is, I can see that two requests(with different parameter) has been executed in my service, and returning two different balances for two accounts. However, in my controller I get two duplicate results. I only get the last response twice.

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with promises, and I'm still new.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be you are returning the same promise for both requests,

```
app.service('userService', function($rootScope, $q){

   this.getAccountsBalance = function(userid, accountNum){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
```

Change it like above and it should work.

Comment: Your answer were good +1, but didn't explain what happening behind the scene. That's why added an answer with suggestion and explanation. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In order to loop through promises, you should use the $q service which provide the $.all method that allows you to resolve only when all promises has been resolved, and then get the data for each promise

Comment: Thanks, but I'm doing the loop in the controller, and the controller calls the service function twice.

Answer (score 0):

When there are multiple promises are involved,if anyone promise get resolved all promise will get resolved with same value.

So you should use `$q.all()` to get result of all promises.

You can do in this way.

Inject [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) Service.

```
var arrAllPromise = [];
for (var i = 0; i < resp.rows; ++i) {
    arrAllPromise[i] = userService.getAccountsBalance($rootScope.userid, resp[i]['Acct_Number'])

}

$q.all(arrAllPromise).then(function(data) {

    console.log(data) // shows two duplicate balances
});
```

It will give all promise data with which it is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Basically problem was you were having common $q object for promise.When your 1st promise gets resolved, the outer $q promiseis resolved by some response.

Then you had 2nd call for the same function, it would make that $http call but return old resolved promise. Because old $q object has fulfilled its promise already.

For solving the problem, you should have separate $q.defer() inside method. So that each time proper data will return by service method

You are creating a custom promise using $q,which is considered as bad pattern. As you have $http.get method is there in place, you can utilize their promise(each $http method promise, and we can chain them using .then)

Service

```
app.service('userService', function($rootScope, $q){
    this.getAccountsBalance = function(userid, accountNum){
        var req = <my $http request>
            //utilize promise object returned by $http
        req.send().then(function(resp){
                    //return data that sent to promise chain function
            return resp.data;       
        });
    }
});
```